# the way to put my own package and compile openwrt

Tags: package, cross-compiling, libraries, dependency-management, openwrt

I wrote my own openwrt package for my script and the compilation stage I put it in the package file as this path openwrt / feeds / package /  is that the path is correct or not?
or if I have is for the compilation error:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `package/test/compile'.  Stop.
make: *** [package/test/compile] Error 2
```

THis my Makefile:

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk
include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/kernel.mk
PKG_NAME:=test
PKG_VERSION:=1.0
PKG_RELEASE:=1 
PKG_BUILD_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_NAME)
DEPENDS:= +nmap +python 



include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

define Package/test
SECTION:=secure
CATEGORY:=Monitoring
TITLE:=test

define Package/test/description
test tis is my first package
endef


define Build/Prepare
mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
$(CP) ./src/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/

endef


define Package/test/install
$(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/bin
$(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/test $(1)/bin/
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,test))
```

I need help please.
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really have to put your source code anywhere in the **/openwrt/** folder. It can be placed, let's say, in /Documents/[name] folder. However it is important that you put your OpenWRT-specific Makefile in the **/openwrt/** tree. I am not sure if putting your Makefile in **/openwrt/feeds/package** is correct but I put my Makefiles in **/openwrt/package/[name] folder** which works fine. Your source code will be automatically copied by the toolchain to the same folder anyway.

Note: if you place your source code somewhere on your system (for example, in the Documents folder) you have to specify the path to it in your Makefile as follows: **PKG_SOURCE_URL:=file://$(TOPDIR)/../Documents/[name]**

Your make[1] errors are basically telling you that the toolchain could not find the Makefile. Try putting Makefile in **/openwrt/package/[name]**.

Comment: thanks @Alex Shp I put only my Makefile in /openwrt/package/name or I put all my folder in which one is Makefile and other folder is src in which one is my scripts

Comment: You only have to put your Makefile in /openwrt/package/name. Your code can be elsewhere, e.g. in home/Documents/myProject. Then add to your Makefile the following line: PKG_SOURCE_URL:=file://$(TOPDIR)/../Documents/myProject and the toolchain will find your code automatically

Comment: @Ales Shp I did like you said to me .I put my make file in openwrt/package/test/Makefile and my script in home/ri/Documents/src but I have the same error :(

Comment: The error you get is because the toolchain doesn't find your Makefile. All I can advise you is to run **make menuconfig** again, choose the package you're compiling and maybe try **make package/test/compile V=99**